# How to make the algorithm more speedy?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists :

```
list1 = [(key1,val_key1), (key2,val_key2)]
list2 = [(key1,val_val1), (key2,val_val2)]
```

Here is my code :

```
for lst1 in list1:
    for lst2 in list2:
        if lst1[0] == lst2[0]:
            list_allpairs.append((lst1[1],lst2[1]))
```

Here is the result:

```
list_allpairs = [(val_key1,val_val1), (val_key2,val_val2)]
```

Is it possible to make the algorithm faster? I think if I use `pop` method for second loop (list2) it should work faster.

Comment: Use list comprehension. A bit fast.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'm parsing logs with ~ 1 000 000 rows. I need something like to merge two list by keys. It works but slowly. I want to improve the code because it works so slowly.

Comment: How do you parse your logs? @albin paul is good enough. But often for parsing logs you are reading them line by line, so you may not need list1 and list2, just generate list_allpairs exactly when you are reading lines from files or database. It will save significant amount of memory and time to build. try to maintain two objects: the dictionaryIndex[key1] that will points to array element in list_allpairs. It still gives you possibility to read two log files in parallel and update list_allpairs

Comment: Lenght of all log file ~6 000 000 rows. I used `grep awk sed`, because they worked fast, and I got two files (~1 000 000 rows) which I needed. I created two lists from them. I didn't manage to read log by one pass, because sometimes data with needed values were before data with keys in log, and I had to get one list with keys by first pass and one with values by second pass. I decided to divide log by two formatted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm runs in  `O(n)` run time complexity. which is faster than your algorithm which runs at `O(n^2)` run time complexity. I use a dictionary to store the keys and values and then compare if one key exists in other and then generate the result.

```
list1 =[('key1','val_key1'), ('key2','val_key2')]

list2 = [('key1','val_val1'), ('key2','val_val2')]

dict2 = {element1:element2 for element1,element2 in list2}

result = []
for key,value in list1:
    if key in dict2:
        result.append((value,dict2[key]))
print(result)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('val_key1', 'val_val1'), ('val_key2', 'val_val2')]
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to construct the second `dict`. You can just construct one `dict` and loop over the other list.

Comment: Well you are correct ;) I have changed the code for your optimization

Comment: You could simplify your `dict2` instanciation by doing `dict2 = dict(list2)`, instead of the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

As Albin paul stated, your algorithm has an order of O(n2). What you need is finding a way to iterate only once.

If your keys are the same, lists having same length and the two lists are sorted, you could do this:

```
pairs = [list(zip(list1[i], list2[i]))[1] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Else you should go for a dict, as the previous answer already proposed.

Comment: sorry, no. that log was made within day. length lists are different. There could be bad data within day or one key from list1 and many values from list2 for that key.